# Retrieve data from databse on button click and display on same jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have my jsp page which has a number of textbox - combo-box filters i recieve the inputs to these from the user and when the user clicks the go button a table is displayed using datatables-tool plugin . I am unable to figure out how to get the data onto same jsp page and retain the contents entered by the user . Please help me out with this .

PS - I retrieve data from database in servlet and send this data to jsp page

Thanks in advance .

Comment: please post some code or more information

Comment: (onclick of test.jsp page button) -> (send the user entered parameters to servlet.java from jsp) -> ( execute query on servlet.java ) -> ( send the result back to test.jsp where result is displayed in a table format using datatables tool plugin )